# Lex: forcing scan?

Tags: c++, c, lex

I'm writing a fairly simple program with LEX, that after parsing a few files, parses input from a user.

Now, with the files, everything works like a charm. However, when it comes to user input from stdin, LEX rules won't run until an EOF (via ctrl+D) character is sent. When I do that, LEX parses all I wrote and then waits for more input. A second consecutive EOF terminates the scanner.

Thing is, I want the program to react on `\n`, outputting some data. Is there a way to force a scan from inside a rule, or to configure LEX buffering somehow to match this behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved! This did the trick:

```
%option always-interactive
```

I'm leaving this here for future reference, in case... well, who knows.

Comment: Consider accepting your answer so this will show up as having an accepted answer.

Comment: @QuantumMechanic I have wait 2 days to do that :) 23 hours left

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet from a unix shell I did with lex and yacc.  I think it'll do the trick.

```
"\n"                    |
";"                     {
                        //yylval.sb = getsb(yytext);  for yacc stuff
                        fprintf(stderr,"EOL\n");
                        return(EOL);
                        }
```

Comment: The semi colon was just for doing mulitple commands on one line within the shell.